# Добавление нескольких записей в цикле

Tags: php, mysql

После прохождения цикла, в таблицу БД заносится только последняя запись, когда как каждая запись должна заносится, на каждой итерации цикла. Где я мог ошибиться?

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($mas)){

        $id = $row['id'];
        $discipline = $row['discipline'];
        $fc = $row['fc'];
        $fl = $row['fl'];
        $profile = $row['profile'];
        $group = $row['class'];
        $course_semestr = $row['course_semestr'];
        $count_students = $row['count_students'];
        $groups = $row['groups'];
        $subgroups = $row['subgroups'];
        $lection = $row['lection'];
        $seminar = $row['seminar'];
        $lab = $row['lab'];

    $upd = "INSERT INTO result (discipline,fc,fl,profile,group,course_semestr,count_students,count_group,count_podgroup,lectures,seminar,lab) VALUES ($discipline,$fc,$fl,$profile,$group,$course_semestr,$groups,$subgroups,$lection,$seminar,$lab)";
       mysql_query($upd);
       if($upd == TRUE) {
        echo "Удача";
       }
       else {echo "Неудача";}
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас в result столбцов больше чем в VALUES вы там потеряли count_students